# JavaFX - ListView doesnot populated data from fxml

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I'm trying to populate list view with fxml but while running my program the method `setCellFactory` for somehow doesn't called by my `ListView`.
Is some one can help my and explain me how to fix my code?

listviewContoller.java -->

```
public class ListViewController implements Initializable {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @FXML
    private ListView listView;

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ObservableList observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            arrayList.add("String 1");
            arrayList.add("String 2");
            arrayList.add("String 3");
            arrayList.add("String 4");
            observableList.setAll(arrayList);
            listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                    return new ListViewCell();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

ListViewCell.java -->

```
public class ListViewCell extends ListCell<String> {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String string, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(string, empty);
        if(string != null) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setInfo(string);
            setGraphic(data.getBox());
        } else {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setInfo("AAAA");
            setGraphic(data.getBox());
        }
    }
}
```

Data.java -->

```
public class Data  implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private HBox hBox;

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageListCell;

    @FXML
    private Label labelListCell;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Tracker/UI/listCellItem.fxml"));
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void setInfo(String string) {
        labelListCell.setText(string);
    }

    public HBox getBox() {
        return hBox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`setCellFactory` ***is*** called, but you use a cell that does not display the content in any way:

Creating a instance of `Data` won't load the fxml and without the fxml being loaded, `getBox()` always returns `null`.

BTW: It would be a good idea to reuse `Data` to avoid having to reload the fxml.

---

Usually in a case like this you create a custom `Node` type with the content loaded from fxml:

```
public class Data extends HBox {

    public Data() {
        // load fxml here
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Tracker/UI/listCellItem.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.setRoot(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageListCell;

    @FXML
    private Label labelListCell;

    public void setInfo(String string) {
        labelListCell.setText(string);
    }

}
```

**listCellItem.fxml**

```xml
<!-- no fx:controller attribute allowed here -->
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <!-- contents of the root tag of the old fxml should be copied here -->
</fx:root>
```

Note that you should also copy all attributes of the root element of the old fxml, but for the `fx:controller` attribute.

```
public class ListViewCell extends ListCell<String> {

    private final Data data;

    public ListViewCell() {
        this.data = new Data();
        setGraphic(this.data);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String string, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(string, empty);

        data.setInfo(string == null ? "AAAA" : string);
    }
}
```

---

Furthermore you never set the new value of the `items` property:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    arrayList.add("String 1");
    arrayList.add("String 2");
    arrayList.add("String 3");
    arrayList.add("String 4");
    observableList.setAll(arrayList);
    listView.setItems(observableList);
    ...
}
```

Moreover instead of using `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, why not simply add `<String>` as type parameter???

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do everything as you said but still nothing happens..

Comment: @DanaS Did you use the `ListViewController` with the fxml containing the `ListView`? This is the only place I see where something still could still go wrong. If this is not the issue, add a break point or a `println` to the `initialize` method and the `updateItem` methods to check, which ones are called and which are not...

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add Object in list view

In Example below I have created a list item in fxml and add that item in list view using for loop

See the source for Example

**ListViewExample FXML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="389.0" prefWidth="471.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="customlistview.ListViewExampleController">
  <children>
      <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="389.0" prefWidth="517.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**ListViewExampleController Code**

```
package customlistview;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
    import javafx.util.Callback;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

    /**
     *
     * @author hemant-pc
     */
    public class ListViewExample implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private ListView listView;

        @FXML
        Pane pane;

        public ListViewExample() {
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            try {
                ObservableList<Pane> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ListItem.fxml"));
                    Pane listItem = fxmlLoader.load();
                    ListItemController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
                    controller.setText("List Item " + i);
                    list.add(listItem);
                }
                listView.getItems().addAll(list);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ListViewExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    }
```

**ListItem FXML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

    <Pane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="317.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="customlistview.ListItemController">
       <children>
          <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="ListItem1" />
          <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="19.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ButtonClick" text="Button" />
       </children>
    </Pane>
```

**ListItemController Code**

```
 package customlistview;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;

    /**
     * FXML Controller class
     *
     * @author hemant-pc
     */
    public class ListItemController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        Label label;

        /**
         * Initializes the controller class.
         */
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO
        }

        @FXML
        public void ButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText(label.getText());
            alert.showAndWait();
        }

        public void setText(String string) {
            label.setText(string);
        }

        public String getText() {
            return label.getText();
        }

    }
```

**Snapshot**

[image]